# AngularJS directives inside ng-repeat not passing evaluated value

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

I just started learning AngularJS two days ago, so if you think I did not approach this in an Angular sort of way then please guide me.
So the code below is part of my HTML which has the ng-repeat directive

```
<div class="row" data-ng-repeat="button in buttons" ng-if="$index % 3 == 0">
   <div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-1">
      <button class="btn btn-default button-width" data-ng-click="my_func('{{buttons[$index].desc}}')">{{buttons[$index].name}}</button>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-1">
      <button class="btn btn-default button-width" data-ng-click="my_func('{{buttons[$index + 1].desc}}')">{{buttons[$index + 1].name}}</button>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-1">
      <button class="btn btn-default button-width" data-ng-click="my_func('{{buttons[$index + 2].desc}}')">{{buttons[$index + 2].name}}</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

The following code is my Angular Controller which is passing the values to the ng-repeat directive in the HTML and then the ng-click directive in the HTML is calling the my_func function in the controller.

```
remote_app.controller("remote-controller", function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.buttons = [{
        "desc": "OFF_V1",
        "name": "OFF",
    }, {
        "desc": " ",
        "name": " ",
    }, {
        "desc": "SOURCE_1",
        "name": "SOURCE",
    }];
    $scope.my_func = function(command) {
        $http.get("http://localhost:1337?comm=" + command).success(function() {
            $scope.result = "Sent to server - " + command;
        });
    };
})
```

Now this displays the values fine from the array when the HTML page is rendered but when i click the button which calls the ng-click directive and in turn my_func, the value sent over to the server is not the rendered value of `my_func('OFF_V1')` but instead the value sent is `my_func('{{buttons[$index].desc}}')`. I have tried to find a solution but right now things like $apply and $digest are beyond my understanding of Angular , so any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are passing a string to your function. Also, don't worry about using `{{ }}` in your function calls either, that is for string interpolation. Meaning, you will use `{{ }}` inside your html in order to write that value to the view.

Comment: Thanks @TjGienger, yes I understand now. I thought that i needed that for $index but now I know that i don't need that for that.

Comment: You can also simply pass index like `function($index)` which is nice for array manipulation.

Comment: @TjGienger, sorry i don't quite follow . Can you please explain a bit more ?

Comment: admittedly I didn't look over you code much, BUT you can just pass the `$index` into the function and access that specific button from the array inside the controller rather than all that stuff in the html.

Comment: @TjGienger, aah now I see what you mean, yes that is a great idea. Will do it like that, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you pass without `''` then you will get value as angular will parse his expression into value. but after using `''` angular will consider it as a string then it stop parsing. if you wanna to send value try to use without `''` but it is recommended not to pass with angular expression(`{{}}`) either way value will be passed

Try like this

```
data-ng-click="my_func(buttons[$index].desc)"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @anik this works, didn't realise that it was trying to evaluate it as a string. Will mark this as the correct answer, right now it is saying i can accept this answer in 5 minutes.